# change of mouse click points which were created by using canvas

Tags: jquery, canvas, mouseevent, mouseclick-event

I had created points using canvas and jquery mouseclick events. When the user double clicks on the point(which is already created by mouse click event) should change its position according to the mouse cursor movement.Is it possible with canvas and jquery? or should i use svg?
Here goes my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<body>

<p>mouseclick</p>

<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" style="cursor:crosshair"></canvas>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$("#canvas").click(function(e){


  getPosition(e); 
 drawCoordinates(x,y);
});

var pointSize = 3;

function getPosition(event){


var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();



var x = event.clientX - rect.left;



var y = event.clientY - rect.top;

 drawCoordinates(x,y);
}

function drawCoordinates(x,y,canvas){   



var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");


ctx.fillStyle = "#ff2626"; // Red color

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(x, y, pointSize, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
ctx.fill();
}

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

```js
$("#canvas").click(function(e) {
  getPosition(e);
  drawCoordinates(x, y);
});

var pointSize = 3;

function getPosition(event) {
  var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
  var x = event.clientX - rect.left;
  var y = event.clientY - rect.top;

  drawCoordinates(x, y);
}

function drawCoordinates(x, y, canvas) {
  var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");


  ctx.fillStyle = "#ff2626"; // Red color

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, pointSize, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
  ctx.fill();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>mouseclick</p>
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" style="cursor:crosshair"></canvas>
```